# How can I search a linked list of objects for a specific field?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am writing a program that stores objects of my class "TeamRecord" into a linked list. I am having issues getting the search method to work. The code below works for a linked list that only contains strings, but since this is a linked list of TeamRecord objects I need to figure out how to only look at the team name field.

calling the search method:

```
case 5:     
    System.out.println("Enter team name to search: ");
    String input = console.next();

    if(teams.search(input))
        System.out.println(input + " is a team.");
    else
    System.out.println(input + " is not a team.");

    break;
```

I get an error because String input cannot be converted to TeamRecord

Search method:

```
public boolean search(E element) {
  if(isEmpty())
     return false;
  //create a new node for the element

  Node<E> temp = new Node<E>(element, null);
  temp = head;

  while(temp != null)
  {
     if(temp.getElement().equals(element))
        return true;

     temp = temp.getNext();
  }

  return false; 
}
```

I tried this:

```
if(teams.getTeamName().search(input))
```

That doesn't work though because "teams" is the name of the LinkedList so I'm not actually looking at individual objects. I'm not really sure how to approach this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated

I will post the rest of the code here in case the above isn't enough:

```
public class TeamRecord implements Comparable<TeamRecord>{

private String teamName;
private int totalWin;
private int totalLoss;

public TeamRecord() {
}

public TeamRecord(String teamName, int totalWin, int totalLoss) {
    this.teamName = teamName;
    this.totalWin = totalWin;
    this.totalLoss = totalLoss;
}

public String getTeamName() {
    return teamName;
}

public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
    this.teamName = teamName;
}

public int getTotalWin() {
    return totalWin;
}

public void setTotalWin(int totalWin) {
    this.totalWin = totalWin;
}

public int getTotalLoss() {
    return totalLoss;
}

public void setTotalLoss(int totalLoss) {
    this.totalLoss = totalLoss;
}

public int compareTo(TeamRecord T) {
    return this.teamName.compareTo(T.teamName);

}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\n\nTeam Name: " + teamName + "\nTotal Wins: " + totalWin + 
            "\nTotal Losses: " + totalLoss;
}



}
```

Linked List:

```
public class MyLinkedList<E> {

   //data members
   private Node<E> head;
   private Node<E> tail;

   int size;

      //contructor
   public MyLinkedList(){
      head = null;
      tail = null;
      size = 0;
   }

   public boolean isEmpty(){
      if(head == null)
         return true;

      return false;
   }

   public int size(){
      return size;
   }

   public void addFirst(E element){

      //create a new node for the element

      Node<E> temp = new Node(element, null);

      //if the list is empty
      if(isEmpty()){
         head = temp;
      }
      else{
         //temp's next = head
         temp.setNext(head);
         head = temp;

      }
      size++;
   } 

   public E removeFirst() throws EmptyListException {

      if(isEmpty()) 
         throw new EmptyListException("This list is empty.");

      Node<E> temp = head;

         //move head to head next
      head = head.getNext();

      E result = temp.getElement();

      temp.setNext(null);
      temp = null;

      size--;

      return result;

   }
   public void addLast(E element) {

      //create a new node for the element

      Node<E> temp = new Node<E>(element, null);

      if(head != null)
      {
         Node<E> tail = head;
         while(tail.getNext() != null)
         {
            tail = tail.getNext();
         }
         tail.setNext(temp);
      }
      else
         head = temp;

      size++;

   }

   public boolean search(E element) {
      if(isEmpty())
         return false;
      //create a new node for the element

      Node<E> temp = new Node<E>(element, null);
      temp = head;

      while(temp != null)
      {
         if(temp.getElement().equals(element))
            return true;

         temp = temp.getNext();
      }

      return false; 
   }

   public String traverse(){

      if(isEmpty())
         return "Empty list";

      String result = "Head --->";

      int i = size;

      Node<E> temp = head;

      while(i > 0){
         result += temp.getElement();
         temp = temp.getNext();
         i--;
      }
      return result;
   }

}//end of class
```

Node class:

```
 class Node<E> {

   //data members
   private E element;
   private Node<E> next;

   //constructors
   public Node() {
      this(null, null);
   }

   public Node(E element, Node<E> next) {
      this.element = element;
      this.next = next;
   }

   //setters and getters
   public void setElement(E element) {
      this.element = element;
   }

   public void setNext(Node<E> next) {
      this.next = next;
   }

   public E getElement() {
      return element;
   }

   public Node<E> getNext() {
      return next;
   }

}
```

Client:

```
public class TeamRecordClient {

   static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static int main(String [] args) {

      MyLinkedList<TeamRecord> teams = new MyLinkedList();


      boolean flag = true;
      int userCommand;
      while (flag) {
         showMenu();

         userCommand = console.nextInt();

         switch (userCommand) {
              //addFirst
            case 1:
               System.out.println("Enter Team Name: ");
               String name = console.next();

               System.out.println("Enter Total Wins: ");
               int totalWins = console.nextInt();

               System.out.println("Enter Total Losses: ");
               int totalLosses = console.nextInt();

               teams.addFirst(new TeamRecord(name, totalWins, totalLosses));


               break;
              //removeFirst
            case 2:
               try{
                  TeamRecord result = teams.removeFirst();

                  System.out.println("Removed Team: " + teams.toString());
               }
               catch(EmptyListException e) {
                  System.out.println(e.toString());
               }
               break;
              //addLast
            case 3:
               System.out.println("Enter Team Name: ");
               String name1 = console.next();

               System.out.println("Enter Total Wins: ");
               int totalWins1 = console.nextInt();

               System.out.println("Enter Total Losses: ");
               int totalLosses1 = console.nextInt();

               teams.addLast(new TeamRecord(name1, totalWins1, totalLosses1));

               break;
              //traverse
            case 4:
               System.out.println(teams.traverse());

               break;
              //search for a element
            case 5:     
               System.out.println("Enter team name to search: ");
               String input = console.next();

               if(teams.search(input))
                  System.out.println(input + " is a team.");
               else
                  System.out.println(input + " is not a team.");

               break;

            case 0:
               flag = false;
               break;
            default:
         }
      }//end main
   }     
   private static void showMenu() {
      System.out.print("\n\n"
                + "\n1 - Add First"
                + "\n2 - Remove First"
                + "\n3 - Add Last"
                + "\n4 - Traverse"
                + "\n5 - Search"
                + "\n6 - Selection Sort(Team Name)"
                + "\n7 - Quick Sort(Total Wins)"
                + "\n0 - Exit "
                + "\nEnter a command: ");
   }

}//end of class
```

Comment: This is impossible with the current implementation. You do not have any way to get an element out of your `LinkedList` except `removeFirst()`, but this will destroy the List. Also, you should override `equals(Object other)` in `TeamRecord`.

Comment: You could let `search()` take a predicate, which is IMHO the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you modify your `search()` method to take a Predicate instead:

```
public boolean search(Predicate<? super E> predicate) {
    Node<E> temp = head;
    while (temp != null) {
        if (predicate.test(temp.getElement()))
            return true;
       temp = temp.getNext();
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Then you can specify any `Predicate` for the search:

```
if (teams.search(e -> e.getTeamName().equals(input))
    System.out.println(input + " is a team.");
else
    System.out.println(input + " is not a team.");
```